# Perl WWW::Mechanize from string variable

Tags: html, perl, parsing, dom, mechanize

In Perl, using module [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) (required, not other module), is it possible to "parse" document from string variable, instead of url?

I mean instead of

```
       $mech->get($url);
```

to do something like

```
       $html = '<html...';
       $mech->???($html);
```

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
          $mech->get(0);
          $mech->update_html('<html>...</html>');
```

It works!

Comment: what a silly interface.  No wonder I couldn't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the data to disk and then get() it in the usual manner.  Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Temp;
use URI::File;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $data = '<html><body>foo</body></html>';

# write the data to disk
my $fh = File::Temp->new;
print $fh $data;
$fh->close;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get( URI::file->new( $fh->filename ) );

print $mech->content;
```

prints: <html><body>foo</body></html>

Comment: I'd just use File::Temp to write the data to disk and get send it to mechanize with $mech->get(URI::file->new($tempfilename))

Comment: @singingfish Thanks very much for pointing that out.  I've updated my example accordingly.  Pares the code down nicely.

Answer (score -2):

Not really. You could try getting the `HTTP::Response` object using `$mech->response` and then using that object's `content` method to replace the content with your own string. But you would have to adjust all the message headers as well and it would get quite messy.

What is it that you want to do? The methods like `forms` and `images` that `WWW::Mechanize` provides are based on other modules and are fairly simple to code.

Comment: I need to analyze HTML code that was fetched by other program and passed into as an input.